# Updating all pages in a Google Site with setHtmlContent using a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm a novice trying to modify script from James Ferreira's excellent book and I'm running into trouble.  I'd like to update all the existing pages in a Google site from a spreadsheet using setHtmlContent. I can change one page, but not all of them.  Is this possible?  This is the script I am working with:

```
function updatePages()
{
  var pages = SitesApp.getSite('site', 'scriptbetatest').getAllDescendants();
  var key =  '00000000000000000000000000000000000';
  var sheet = 'Sheet1';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(key).getSheetByName(sheet);
  var productDetails = rangeToObjects(ss.getDataRange().getValues());

  for (var i = 0; i < productDetails.length; ++i)
  {
    var page = pages[0].setHtmlContent('<div>'+'</div>')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though you want to replace zero with i:

```
var page = pages[i].setHtmlContent('<div>'+'</div>')
```